# Excel VBA data validation swap only working in debug mode

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I ran into a problem with an excel VBA project I am working on.

I have a segment of code that switches the data validation in a table when an activeX checkbox is ticked. Now it throws an error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" when I attempt to modify or add data validation. However it DOES work in the debugger when I step through the segment of code AND manually check the cells data validation via the data ribbon in excel.

Here is a simplified sample of the code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value Then
    With Range("e4")
        .ClearContents
        .Validation.Delete
        .Validation.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, "=lst_b"
    End With
Else
    With Range("e4")
        .ClearContents
        .Validation.Delete
        .Validation.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, "=lst_a"
    End With

End If
```

Again, this does work ONLY when I step through the code and physically open the data validation window via the toolbar after line 5 and 11. There is no validation when I check and I can continue the code execution without a problem.

This was working earlier and I do not understand why my code stopped working as I was not modifying this part of the code when it broke.

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated. 
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you,

EDIT:
So just got to a different machine and set up a test work space to work on this issue and the exact same code works as before. Is there any reason why this would change on a different machine? (Both running excel 2013)

Comment: Worksheet is Protected?

Comment: No, It is not protected

Comment: Which line the error is on? You may want to try avoid using ActiveSheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input here everyone. It appears that excel 2013 has had an issue with the kind of list name that goes into these combo boxes for data validation. I used the solution here:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/09/18/worksheet-combo-box-problem-in-excel-2013/

What is needed to be done is to create another list that references the list that is referencing your table data. I cant believe that this is what is needed to be done as a fix.

If anyone has an explanation as to why this "solution" works or why you can not just reference the list data first hand I would be happy to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that initial state of CheckBox1 is unchecked == False.
Declare private `bCheckBox1` on the module level and try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private bCheckBox1 As Boolean

...

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim sStr$

    bCheckBox1 = Not bCheckBox1
    Select Case bCheckBox1
        Case True:  sStr = "=lst_b"
        Case False: sStr = "=lst_a"
    End Select

    With Range("e4")
        .ClearContents
        .Validation.Delete
        .Validation.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, sStr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Drop the Select Case and use `sStr = IIf(bCheckBox1,"=lst_b","=lst_a")`

Comment: Take it easy. Do not chase on one-line-coding! 1 - `IIf` unconditionally calc both parts regardless of condition, but `Select Case` - only true. If one of parts are error - division to zero, for example, `Iif`raise error, when `Select Case` - none. . 2- `Select Case` more readable and, it's importnat, more writable, when code need in refactoring.